# Adding a toggle to basic jQuery accordion affect

Tags: jquery

Just like the toggle provided by default with the HTML tag **details** and **summary** ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rH2c9/)), I am trying to get a little toggle to appear to the left hand side of this basic jQuery accordion effect, like this (PNG):

[image]

So far I have this code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfzT2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">TOGGLE ONE</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">TOGGLE TWO</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer; margin: 0;}
.accordion-content {display: none;}
.accordion-content.default {display: block;}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

        //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it anyway. (I can't say there isn't a better way.)

You can insert a `<span>` as the first child of the toggle (`<h4>`) elements. It should have the `display` set to `inline-block`. It can then be given a width and height and a background image. This image will be the arrow pointing to the right.

When a toggle is open (i.e., it is displaying the content), another class is added to the `<span>` to change the arrow to point down.

Rather than use two image files, I created a single image file which contains both icons. (I used the arrows you show in the question.) The `background-position` style setting is used to choose the icon within the image file.

Here's the CSS for the two classes. The `<span>` elements always have the "icon" class, but only have the "icon-open" class when they are open:

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('http://s14.postimg.org/cx1k4l135/ui_icons_222222_256x240.png');
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -32px -16px;
}
.icon-open {
    background-position: -64px -16px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
    var $toggles = $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle');

    $toggles.click(function () {
        var $toggle = $(this),
            $content = $toggle.next(),
            $arrow = $toggle.children(':first'),
            isOpen = $arrow.hasClass('icon-open');

        $arrow.toggleClass('icon-open', !isOpen);
        $toggles.children(':first').not($arrow).removeClass('icon-open');

        $content.slideToggle('fast');
        $(".accordion-content").not($content).slideUp('fast');

    }).prepend('<span class="icon"></span>');
});
```

<kbd>[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgMcV/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Wow, thanks for the effort. I did find something similar, but I am carefully reviewing what you did. The main problem I have is I am trying to accomplish something like this with images in the actual site: http://snag.gy/PVrAe.jpg   Since the arrows now use the bg image, I am not sure how to implement it. Every way I try and implement it, the images end up getting cropped.

Comment: @fakeguybrushthreepwood - If you have a link for the "something similar" that you found, please share it. I basically looked at how the arrows work for the [JQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Comment: @JohnS You can use unicode for the arrows; see this answer I just wrote a few hours ago.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343744/make-the-contents-of-a-details-tag-animate-when-open-with-jquery-js/21345510#21345510 it's more than closely related. 1+

Comment: @JoshC - Thanks for showing me that. I've never used the `:before` selector before. Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7h3y/) reworked to use unicode characters for the arrows and the `:before` selector instead of a `<span>`.