# Smooth opening of the accordion using JavaScript + jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I can’t open the accordion smoothly, I can’t figure out what the problem is?
HTML code must remain unchanged.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example of smooth opening of an accordion using jQuery</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #1b1b1b;
        color: #ccc;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <details>
      <summary>Details:</summary>
      <ul>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        const details = $("details");
        const content = details.find("ul");
        details.on("click", (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          content.slideToggle(1000);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried this option - the effect is the opposite, the contents of the accordion quickly open when pressed, and then close immediately but slowly. I expected it to open slowly.

```
    <details>
      <summary>Details:</summary>
      <ul>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
```

```
    var animationTime = 2000;

    $("details > summary").click(function() {

        $(this).next().stop().slideToggle(animationTime);

    });
```

Comment: hi, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/40043602/11139453